# Cloud Function ArrayRemove not deleting array value, but function runs without error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My cloud function is not deleting value from the array it is suppose to. It gets all the values correctly as I see in my debug console, but the value in the array is still there.

My code statement is as follows:

```
  for (const id of membersUnderStructure){
    const ele = context.params.structure;
    console.log(`Deleting ${ele} From ${id}`);
    await db.collection(`TeamMember`)
    .doc(id)
    .update({teamStructIds: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(ele)})
```

I know the problem is with the ***admin.firestore....*** line as if I put a constant value there, it does update fine. My console shows the correct value of '**ele**' and '**id**' as well, so the values are correct. The function executes '**ok**' without any error but does NOT delete the value of '**ele**' from the '**teamStructIds**' array.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The Array is of 'Number' and it is trying to delete a String of 'ele'.
I just changed to parseInt(context.parama.structure) and it works now.